# Can anyone help me to draw this table?

Tags: tables, multirow

I wanna draw in LaTeX the following table. But I found it is rather difficult, especially the header, which contains some non-vertical lines. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show what you tried so far. Are you bound to using some specific packages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did not show any MWE, so it is unclear which packages you (want to) use, but with the `nicematrix` package you could do the following:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines]{ *{7}{ w{c}{1cm} } }
\Block[name=dd]{2-1}{} & \Block{1-3}{AAA} & & & \Block{1-3}{BBB} & & \\
  & X & Y & Z & X & Y & Z \\
  &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
  &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
\CodeAfter
\tikz{
    \draw (1 -| 1) -- (2 -| 2) (1 -| 1) -- (3 -| 2);
    \node[anchor=east] at ([yshift=7pt]dd.east) {\footnotesize U};
    \node[anchor=east] at ([yshift=-4pt]dd.east) {\footnotesize V};
    \node[anchor=south] at ([xshift=-5pt]dd.south) {\footnotesize W};
}
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]